# 2sxc - Calculated vars between razor and JS on a @foreach loop

Tags: javascript, razor, 2sxc

I'm creating a view with two text inputs ('est' being calculated via JS based on 'idd') on top, and then a table with a @foreach loop to display all my data. Some fields will be calculated based on each other, but others must be calculated after the page is loaded, every time the 'est' and/or 'idd' inputs change.

Since razor is calculated server side and this JS client side, how can I set these type of calculated columns like the one in this example:

```
This should be the myResult var (or 'est' value) + @Content.V2
```

I though about pulling the @Content.EntityId to set some dynamic var names like:

```
<input type="text" id="@Content.EntityId-newfield"">
```

and pulling some `<script>get the myResult again, add @Content.V2, set document.getElementById('@Content.EntityId-newfield').value</script>` inside the loop but it doesn't work.

How can I achieve this?

Here's the full page:

```
<h1>My page</h1>
<br>
idd: <input type="text" id="idd" oninput="calculate()"> __ est: <input type="text" id="est">
<br><br>
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>V1</th>
            <th>V2</th>
            <th>V1 / V2</th>
            <th>Field I know not how to calculate</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var Content in AsDynamic(Data["Default"])){
        <tr>
            <td>@Edit.Toolbar(Content, actions: "edit,replace")</td>
            <td>@Content.EntityId</td>
            <td>@Content.Title</td>
            <td>@Content.V1</td>
            <td>@Content.V2</td>
            <td>@Math.Round(@Content.V1 / @Content.V2, 2)</td>
            <td>This should be the myResult var (or 'est' value) + @Content.V2</td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    function calculate() {
        var idade = document.getElementById('idd').value;
        var myResult = (parseInt(idade) + 4) * 2;
        document.getElementById('est').value = myResult;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Here's a test to try to fetch the myResult var that also does not work.

https://pastebin.com/NV4SXWup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure an array of functions would do the trick.

Before @foreach:

```
var arrayOfFunctions = [];
<input type="text" id="peso" oninput="callFunctions()">
```

inside @foreach:

```
arrayOfFunctions.push(function(setPeso) { document.getElementById('@Content.EntityId').value = setPeso * @Content.fieldToCalculate; });
```

after: @foreach:

```
function callFunctions() {
    var myPeso = parseInt(document.getElementById('peso').value);
    arrayOfFunctions.forEach(f => f(myPeso));
}
```